# Change style of webparts without SharePoint Designer

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013

I have kind of a special problem: I need to change the style of some WebParts in SharePoint 2013 without using SharePoint Designer.

In detail, I want to add padding to a WebPart, because the bullets of the list inside my WebPart are directly aligned to the left border, which looks broken.

Has anyone an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Can you add screenshot? Also can you provide details which web part are you using?

Comment: I'm not able to attach a screenshot or to provide a link, since this is my first post and apparently this functionality is locked for new users.
The web part is a list with bullets and text.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do that but they would most likely all revolve around css. Simplest (and probably ugliest) way I can think of is adding a script editor to your page and fill it with the relevant css to adjust your web part's s display of the list. As Max has implied, answering your question would depend on what web part you're using and how you're using it.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not able to attach a screenshot or provide a link, since this is my first post and apparently this functionality is locked for new users. 
The web part is a list with bullets and text.